# как переписать рекурсивный алгоритм на итеративный

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия

Вопрос скорее представляет из себя спортивный интерес, нежели что-то  очень сильно необходимое

Вобщем, есть довольно банальный алгоритм генерации всевозможных перестановок строки с факториальной сложностью.

```
void permutations(std::string s, int pos = 0)
{
    if (pos >= s.size())
    {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = pos; i < s.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::swap(s[i], s[pos]);
            permutations(s, pos + 1);
            std::swap(s[i], s[pos]);
        }
    }
}
```

Из теории известно, что любую рекурсию можно переписать итеративно, при помощи эмуляции стека

**update**
как это сделать в этом случае не применяя никаких структур данных для эмуляции стека вызовов ?

Comment: Если вы запрещаете эмулировать рекурсию вручную, при помощи явного стека (очереди и т.п.), то тогда вам придется отказаться и от "теории", согласно которой "любую рекурсию можно переписать итеративно". В общем случае "переписывание рекурсии итеративно" возможно именно и только через переход к явному стеку. Имено это и имеет в виду "теория". В данном случае задача может быть решена без рекурсии, но не в общем случае.

Comment: @AnT ок, отказываюсь

Comment: Мне кажется, более интересным был бы вопрос не «без применения структур для эмуляции стека» (в конце-концов, кто сказал, что я применяю очередь для эмуляции стека, а не просто так?), а «О(1) по памяти».

Comment: Решений у задачи несколько. Самое известное можно найти, например, [здесь](http://prog-cpp.ru/permutation/). Не задавая вопрос на SO, можно было найти решение через гугл меньше чем за полторы минуты.

Comment: @Zealint гуглом я умею пользоваться, ненадо тут, весь смысл в том, чтобы здесь кто то своё уникальное решение предоставил

Comment: @ampawd, тогда именно так и следовало бы сформулировать вопрос: покажите кто какие варианты знает. Сейчас из вопроса следует, что вы ищите один какой-то вариант без эмуляции стека. Можно было бы даже устроить конкурс на самое "красивое" нерекурсивное решение.

Answer (score 3):

Самый тупой и универсальный вариант - эмуляция рекурсии с помощью стека:

```
void permutations(const string& s)
{
    struct item { string s; int pos; };
    stack<item>task;
    task.push(item{s,0});
    while(!task.empty())
    {
        item i = task.top();
        task.pop();
        if (i.pos >= i.s.size())
        {
            std::cout << i.s << '\n';
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = i.pos; j < i.s.size(); ++j)
            {
                std::swap(i.s[j], i.s[i.pos]);
                task.push(item{i.s,i.pos+1});
                std::swap(i.s[j], i.s[i.pos]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а, ну, я забыл отметить что стек эмулировать нельзя ))

Comment: Тогда лезем в том 4А Кнута и используем любой из приведенных там алгоритмов генерации перестановок. Потому как, насколько я помню, непосредственно без стека устраняется только оконечная рекурсия (это даже компиляторы делают). В данном случае это не она, так что алгоритм надо в той или иной мере переделывать. Imho :)

Comment: @ampawd: Ну вы же сами сказали: "Из теории известно, что любую рекурсию можно переписать итеративно". Эта теория имеет в виду *именно* то, что всегда есть возможность "эмуляции стека". Без "эмуляции стека"  в общем случае невозможно "перписать рекурсию итеративно". В данном случае вам повезло: итеративный алгорим существует - хорошо известный алгоритм Нарайаны (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B). Но в общем случае - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать не рекурсивный [Алгоритм Нарайаны](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B), его сложность O(n).

Алгоритм:

> Шаг 1: найти такой наибольший j, для которого a[j] < a[j + 1].
>
> Шаг 2: увеличить a[j]. Для этого надо найти наибольшее l , для которого a[l] > a[j]. Затем поменять местами a[j] и a[l].
>
> Шаг 3: записать последовательность a[j + 1] ,..., a[n] в обратном порядке.